# How To Prevent Hibernate From Dropping My Tables

Tags: hibernate, schema, alter-table, sql-drop

I am running into some serious issues with hibernate. It is dropping! my tables. Digging through the logs I find these two lines of code

```
    Hibernate: drop table if exists REFERENCES
    Hibernate: drop table if exists ACCOUNTS
```

Now whatever might be the difference in entity specifications, I would expect Hibernate NOT to drop my table. Besides this, in my experience I have found that it is RANDOMLY dropping data and altering it inside database as well.

Now this obviously [as apparent] a serious issue. How do I prevent hibernate from altering my SQL schema? Id rather have it throw fatal exceptions than screw up my database!

Comment: Have you enabled the following property in your persistence.xml file or hibernate.cfg.xml  **<property name="show_sql">true</property>** This will help you get your queries more proper..

Comment: I solved it by removing a property that caused creation of table. Now it is not meddling...

Comment: @Ace what is that property?

Answer (score 2):

I think changing the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property would solve your problem.

Setting it to `validate` or `update` would work as you want it to from what I can understand.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147995/8043741) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update will prevent from automatically dropping the table on each run. For me it was set to create.