# INSERT INTO table SELECT not working with constant values in H2 DB

Tags: sql, h2, liquibase, h2db

Following is the H2DB query

```
 INSERT INTO userpermission (userid, permissionid, createddt, createdby, updateddt, updatedby)
            SELECT u.userid, p.permissionid, now(), ("1"), now(), ("1") FROM user u, permission p
            WHERE u.email = "csr_admin@example.com";
```

What I am trying to achieve is to insert a record into userpermission for user with given email address in user table, for each permission in permission table.

Following is the error

```
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Column "1" not found; SQL statement:
                                    INSERT INTO userpermission (userid, permissionid, createddt, createdby, updateddt, updatedby)
                                                SELECT u.userid, p.permissionid, now(), ("1"), now(), ("1") FROM user u, permission p
                                                WHERE u.email = "csr_admin@example.com" [42122-193] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO userpermission (userid, permissionid, createddt, createdby, updateddt, updatedby)
                                                SELECT u.userid, p.permissionid, now(), ("1"), now(), ("1") FROM user u, permission p
                                                WHERE u.email = "csr_admin@example.com"]
```

The same query is working in MySQL.

Comment: Not sure about H2, but in all RDMS, the constants are declared with single quotes. Also braces are unnecessary. Replace `("1")` with  `'1'`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that before adding braces. Does not work.

Comment: Replace double quotes with single quotes as well. Just run the select statement first. Also you are doing a cross join by not giving join condition. Is that intentional ?

Comment: You are correct. I had to replace the where clause with single quotes. MySQL would accept it but not H2. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. I put the comment as answer as well. Accept it so the question could be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments,

1. Use single quotes for sting constants.
2. Do not use braces with constants in select clause.
3. Check the join condition. Without matching 2 tables based on common column, you are doing a [Cartesian product](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)

Comment: Only the first point is the cause of the error. Braces is optional. 3 is intentional in my case. I am looking to insert values into cross product table for testing which are usually entered manually.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clearing it up as the cartesian product was bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. I want to insert some default value into my H2 when my springboot app first runs. I had the schema.sql and data.sql all correct.

However, It still won't load the sample data into the H2 Schema table when I do `select *`. after looking around for a hour. I decided to look into the `application.properties` file. I changed

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

or `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

both of them work. just in case you wondering why both `none` and `update` works, here is [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)