# Sqlite with hibernate and spring-boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, sqlite

I'm working on a project using maven, hibernate, spring and sqlite3.For the configuration of the connection and hibernate I use the application.yml file which is:

```
spring: 
profile: dev 
jpa:
hibernate:
ddl-auto: create-drop 
properties:
hibernate:
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
datasource:url: jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\database\testrest.db
username: username
password: password
driverClassName: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

The problem every time I start the application my sqlite database is overwritten (so I lose all my tables) and a new one of the same name is created.

Hoping to have your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does exactly spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property works in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-exactly-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-works-in-spring)

Answer (score 2):

The list of possible values for **ddl-auto** for Hibernate are:

- *validate*: validates the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- *update*: updates the schema.
- *create*: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- *create-drop*: create the schema and then drop it when `SessionFactory` is closed explicitly (application is closed).

You should replace *create-drop* with *update* or *validate*