# Hibernate generates extra table

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "past_price")
public class PastPrice {

    @Id
    private String symbol;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Price> prices = null;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public Set<Price> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    public void setPrices(Set<Price> prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }

}
```

And the `Price` entity is like this

```
@Entity
public class Price {
    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
    private String price;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is, create a table with name `past_price` and it has `OneToMany` relationship with `Price` entity. I have hibernate property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` so whenever I run this there are 3 tables created `1. past_price` `2. past_price_prices` and `3. price`. But I am only trying to create 2 tables `past_price` and `price`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-exactly-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-works-in-spring/42147995

Comment: I understand the create or create-drop values of hibernate properties but every time even with different values the table will be generated in the same way.

Comment: in  `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Price> prices = null;` add `targetEntity = Price.class` this one will create only two table price and past_price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @JoinColumn to tell hibernate to create a column in price table and use that for joining. Change your code to below:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_past_price")
private Set<Price> prices = null;
```

This will create a column named fk_past_price in price table and no third table will be created.

P.S.: Use bidirectional association instead if there's no strong reason to go with uni-directional. Like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "past_price")
public class PastPrice {

    @Id
    private String symbol;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pastPrice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Price> prices = null;

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public Set<Price> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    public void setPrices(Set<Price> prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }

}
```

Price:

```
@Entity
public class Price {
    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
    private String price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "past_price_symbol", nullable = false)
    private PastPrice pastPrice;

    public PastPrice getPastPrice() {
      return pastPrice;
    }

    public void setPastPrice(PastPrice pastPrice) {
      this.pastPrice = pastPrice;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem in fact, that you didn't provide other mapping for entities. How would hibernate identify that `Price` related to `PastPrice`? Hibernate couldn't (but I'm not sure) store array of related ids in `Price`.

By default, if you want just 2 tables you need to add field in `Price`:

```
@ManyToOne(...)
private PastPrice pastPrice;
```

In this case, in table Price hibernate generate colymn with id of 'parent' price. Thus, for current mapping 2 tables would be enough.

It would be work something like:

```
select * from Price p join PastPrice pp on pp.id = p.past_price
```

Answer (score 0):

in [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy())

> The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

using targetEntity=price.class

```
 class pastPrice{
         @OneToMany(targetEntity=Price.class,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
         private Set<Price> prices = null;
    }
```

or using mappedby=price

```
class pastPrice{
     @OneToMany(mappedby="Price",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
      private Set<Price> prices = null;
}

   @Entity("Price)
    class Price{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add "mappedBy" to declare which field is relate tables.

also add ManyToOne in Price entity.

Price Entity :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn("past_price_fk")
private PastPrice pastPrice;
```

PastPrice Entity :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pastPrice")
private Set<Price> prices = null;
```