# SpringBoot Hibernate Entity mapping for existing database table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I need to use SpringBoot on a old legacy db where table are already defined and populated.
I don't understand if it's even possible to map an @Entity to an existing table.
I tried to use

```
@Entity
 public class MyTable {...}
```

but every time I launch the SpringBoot application the table is destroyed and recreated empty...
I tried to look in Hibernate Entity annotation doc but I didn't find anything useful. I've seen around some tools, but I would rather do it quickly by hand.

I don't even know if what I intend to do is meaningful, first time using Hibernate.

Comment: are you using spring-data-jpa ?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using springboot-data-jpa in someway, so what you should know is this :

> You can set **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** explicitly and the standard
>   Hibernate property values are **none, validate, update, create**, and
>   **create-drop**. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on
>   whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to
>   create-drop if no schema manager has been detected or none in all
>   other cases. An embedded database is detected by looking at the
>   Connection type. hsqldb, h2, and derby are embedded, and others are
>   not. Be careful when switching from in-memory to a ‘real’ database
>   that you do not make assumptions about the existence of the tables and
>   data in the new platform. You either have to set ddl-auto explicitly
>   or use one of the other mechanisms to initialize the database.

so try to disable the creation of the DDL by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none` in your application.properties

Answer (score 0):

oh, I had spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create in my application.properties....

Answer (score 0):

Since it is already with data I recommend you to set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update so it will not delete anything while restarting the project.
also you can add next properties to get more information about what it is actually executing:
**spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true**

This configuration is added in application.properties file

here you can fin more information:
[how does exactly spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property works in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-exactly-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-works-in-spring)
https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot