# Spring application not creating the table on a Postgres database

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc

Spring doesn't create the table specified in my `@Entity` class in my *Postgres database*.

I've tried a lot of solutions given here in **StackOverflow**, like some changes in the `application.properties`, changing the dialect, setting up the schema etc. I've checked my database permissions and also the user/password information, and it's all fine.

**application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/produtosapirest
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.produtos</groupId>
<artifactId>apirest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>apirest</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Produto.java**

```
package produtos.api.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TB_PRODUTO")
public class Produto implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String nome;
private BigDecimal quantidade;
private BigDecimal valor;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public BigDecimal getQuantidade() {
    return quantidade;
}
public void setQuantidade(BigDecimal quantidade) {
    this.quantidade = quantidade;
}
public BigDecimal getValor() {
    return valor;
}
public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
}
```

}

**terminal**:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-11 10:21:00.011  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] com.produtos.apirest.ApirestApplication  : Starting ApirestApplication on venancio-MS-7817 with PID 16132 (/home/brenorios/eclipse-workspace/apirest/target/classes started by brenorios in /home/brenorios/eclipse-workspace/apirest)
2019-04-11 10:21:00.014  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] com.produtos.apirest.ApirestApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-11 10:21:00.077  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-04-11 10:21:00.077  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-04-11 10:21:00.880  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-04-11 10:21:00.901  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-04-11 10:21:01.283  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84f3c51d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-04-11 10:21:01.672  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-11 10:21:01.698  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-11 10:21:01.698  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-04-11 10:21:01.778  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-11 10:21:01.778  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1701 ms
2019-04-11 10:21:01.988  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-04-11 10:21:02.137  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-04-11 10:21:02.178  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2019-04-11 10:21:02.226  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final}
2019-04-11 10:21:02.227  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-04-11 10:21:02.343  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-04-11 10:21:02.455  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2019-04-11 10:21:02.659  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-04-11 10:21:02.663  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@3046a8a9
2019-04-11 10:21:02.834  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-11 10:21:02.852  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-04-11 10:21:03.042  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-11 10:21:03.087  WARN 16132 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-04-11 10:21:03.347  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-11 10:21:03.349  INFO 16132 --- [  restartedMain] com.produtos.apirest.ApirestApplication  : Started ApirestApplication in 3.783 seconds (JVM running for 4.149)
```

ApirestApplication.java:

```
package com.produtos.apirest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApirestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApirestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Based on the tutorial that I'm following, this setup should result in the creation of the table in the postgres database, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: I would recommend using `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`, to debug and identifying the problem with your application. It will print logs of JPA so you can get to know what is happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured that it was a silly mistake. My main package and the model package weren't with the same name structure, so Spring wasn't getting my models package.

Before:
com.produtosapirest2
com.produtosapi.models

After:
com.produtosapirest2
com.produtosapirest2.models

Comment: Thank you, this is it. I'm dumb.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem probably lies here,

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

If you read more about this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147995/1529092), you can identify that,

> The `update` operation for example will attempt to add new columns, constraints, etc but will never remove a column or constraint that may have existed previously but no longer does as part of the object model from a prior run.

So I would suggest based on your requirements either you use `create` or `create-drop`.

**Note:**

1. `create` and `create-drop` will create DB each time you run the application. So if you don't want that to happen, once you create your DB, change the setting to `update`.
2. **Don't use this configuration in the Production environment.**

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your source code and here are the logs:

```
2019-04-11 19:58:59.345  INFO 15520 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2019-04-11 20:02:42.971  INFO 15520 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-04-11 20:02:42.975  INFO 15520 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@7893aaa9
2019-04-11 20:02:44.848  WARN 15520 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2019-04-11 20:02:44.848  WARN 15520 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "tb_produto_pkey" for table "tb_produto"
2019-04-11 20:02:44.850  INFO 15520 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-04-11 20:02:44.863  INFO 15520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-04-11 20:02:45.067  INFO 15520 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-11 20:02:45.111  WARN 15520 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

You can see that the table got created at the instance 20:02:44.848. This is after 2 minutes of the previous log. Check for `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is set. I have it enabled as part of `@SpringBootApplication`.

Wait till you see the statement printed - "Done---" by altering your Application.java:

```
package produtos.api;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo() {
        return (args) -> {
            System.out.println("Done---");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code from my main file where @SpringBootApplication annotation is.

Comment: @James Jithin  `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is not required to set explicitly, as it will be part of `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @darshgohel, it is the same that is mentioned in my answer!

Comment: @JamesJithin, my bad, maybe I interpreted it wrong. `Check for @EnableAutoConfiguration is set`, this made me confuse. That's why I commented.

Comment: @darshgohel, no worries!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Postgres Dialect. You can try adding the Postgres Dialect inside your properties/yml file as per below:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```