# In Java, Spring maintaining database without any scripts

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on a project in Java (using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Hibernate, JPA, MySql). Every time I create a new Model Class, I have to create a table in the database or if I make any change in the Model class I have to alter the table by myself. Is there any way to avoid this database related stuff. For example I will make Model classes and declare their relationships my Database tables will be generated automatically. In future if I make any changes to my classes they will be applied to the database automatically without loosing any data.

Previously I worked on PHP, Laravel. There all I needed to do is 1) run command `php artisan make:migration create_posts_table`, 2) declare columns like `$table->string('title');`, `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');` and then 3) run command `php artisan migrate`. That's it. No SQL scripts needed. I was wondering if Java, Spring has something like this.

Comment: Actually I think thats bad practice to have database be generated automatically, simply because you have no/limited control over constraint names. Also when a change goes into production, you can only be sure, that the database won't be damaged in any way, if you do it manually

Comment: Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147995/7109162) explains what exactly `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` does

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thanks. I have seen this answer before. But it is not recommended to use in production. That's why I was looking for other options. So if I use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in development and remove from the production, then some modification is done on the project how the modification can be applied to the production part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ideal way

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

In my opinion, the ideal way is to create one SQL file which will create the schema at the startup for us.

---

To let Spring Boot to create it for you

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to "none".
```

*Other Possible values: create, create-drop, validate*

**[More Detailed Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-exactly-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-works-in-spring/42147995)**

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do it.

Use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in your application.properties.

You can also use more advanced tools like https://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do migration using Flyway, it's similar to Laravel migration.

Add the dependency and put your migration SQL files to classpath:db/migration. Flyway will automatically check the sql files version and apply any pending migrations.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot