# Spring Boot / Data doesn't recreate tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, yaml

I'm trying to configure Spring Boot / Data to recreate tables when app initialize.
To this I configured ddl-auto to create. I'm using two data sources.

When tables do not exist, they are created. But when tables exist, they are not recreated. I thought ddl-auto create ("creates the schema, destroying previous data.") would always recreate the tables.

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
   profiles: spring
   jpa:
      generate-ddl: true
      hibernate: 
         ddl-auto: create
      show-sql: true
      properties:
         hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            format_sql: true

dba:
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBA
      username: root
      password: 123
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

dbb:
   datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBB
      username: root
      password: 123
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

My configuration files:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.example.mds"} )
public class EMdsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EMdsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**DBAConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.mds.model"} )
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "dba_emf",
        transactionManagerRef = "dba_tm",
        basePackages = {"com.example.mds.repository"}
)
public class DBAConfig {


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dba_ds")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dba.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dba_dsp") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dba_emf")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dba_ds") DataSource datasource) {
        return builder
                  .dataSource(datasource)
                  .packages("com.example.mds.model")
                  .persistenceUnit("dba_pu")
                  .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dba_tm")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("dba_emf") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dba_dsp")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dba.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }   

}
```

**DBBConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.example.mds.dbb.model"} )
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbb_emf",
        transactionManagerRef = "dbb_tm",
        basePackages = {"com.example.mds.dbb.repository"}
)
public class DBBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dbb_ds")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dbb.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("dbb_dsp") DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbb_emf")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dbb_ds") DataSource datasource) {
        return builder
                  .dataSource(datasource)
                  .packages("com.example.mds.dbb.model")
                  .persistenceUnit("dbb_pu")
                  .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbb_tm")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("dbb_emf") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbb_dsp")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dbb.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `create-drop` property in case you want to drop and create tables. This should be used for testing purposes only and not for production use.
Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring) question for details

Answer (score 1):

In `application.yaml` change `ddl-auto: create to ddl-auto: create-drop`.
It will drop the schema when session factory is closed at application shut down and will create new schema at application startup.

Answer (score 1):

From the question what i understand is that you just want to update the schme when it is already present.But with your current configuration it is only getting created if the tables are not present.You want to update the tables if they are already present.

Please take care to ensure that **you use this property only for test scenarios or for development purposes**.Ensure that you set the `ddl-auto` as `none` for production environment.

Try setting the `application.yml` as below :

```
spring:
   profiles: spring
   jpa:
      generate-ddl: true
      hibernate: 
         ddl-auto: update
```

The possible values for ddl-auto are :

> validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
>   update: update the schema.
>   create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
>   create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

The `update` operation will query the JDBC driver's API to get the database metadata and then Hibernate compares the object model it creates based on reading your annotated classes or HBM XML mappings and will attempt to adjust the schema on-the-fly.

Related post : [How does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property exactly work in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

In `application.yaml` change `ddl-auto: create to ddl-auto: update`.

Comment: Update do not drop and create table again. It is not the correct answer. Update option only adds new columns or create new tables if not existing