# Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [customer_number] in table [customers]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I'm working on **Spring Boot (V2.2.2.RELEASE) and Spring Data JPA** Integration example. In this example, I am validating the schema using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`, using same schema mentioned here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [customer_number] in table [customers]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringBootJpaMysqlComplexApplication.main(SpringBootJpaMysqlComplexApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [customer_number] in table [customers]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [customer_number] in table [customers]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

**application.properties**

```
# MYSQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# JPA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.continueOnError=true

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

**Customer Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customerNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactLastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `contactFirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `addressLine2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `salesRepEmployeeNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditLimit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerNumber`),
  KEY `salesRepEmployeeNumber` (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`salesRepEmployeeNumber`) REFERENCES `employees` (`employeeNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Customer Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerNumber;

    private String addressLine1;

    private String addressLine2;

    private String city;

    private String contactFirstName;

    private String contactLastName;

    private String country;

    private BigDecimal creditLimit;

    private String customerName;

    private String phone;

    private String postalCode;

    private String state;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="salesRepEmployeeNumber")
    private Employee employee;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Order> orders;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Payment
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    private List<Payment> payments;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public int getCustomerNumber() {
        return this.customerNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return this.addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return this.addressLine2;
    }

    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getContactFirstName() {
        return this.contactFirstName;
    }

    public void setContactFirstName(String contactFirstName) {
        this.contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
    }

    public String getContactLastName() {
        return this.contactLastName;
    }

    public void setContactLastName(String contactLastName) {
        this.contactLastName = contactLastName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public BigDecimal getCreditLimit() {
        return this.creditLimit;
    }

    public void setCreditLimit(BigDecimal creditLimit) {
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return this.postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return this.employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return this.orders;
    }

    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    public Order addOrder(Order order) {
        getOrders().add(order);
        order.setCustomer(this);

        return order;
    }

    public Order removeOrder(Order order) {
        getOrders().remove(order);
        order.setCustomer(null);

        return order;
    }

    public List<Payment> getPayments() {
        return this.payments;
    }

    public void setPayments(List<Payment> payments) {
        this.payments = payments;
    }

    public Payment addPayment(Payment payment) {
        getPayments().add(payment);
        payment.setCustomer(this);

        return payment;
    }

    public Payment removePayment(Payment payment) {
        getPayments().remove(payment);
        payment.setCustomer(null);

        return payment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception: Schema-validation: missing column [customer_number] in table [customers]

Comment: @dassum - Yes, but if you look at table and entity, you'll find both, I am not sure if latest version of Hibernate expecting some kind of strategy naming

Comment: The DDL for your customer table doesn't have a customer_number column.

Comment: field variable name is camel case and hibernate adds underscore in between, however we need to implement strategy it seem, but even if adding strategy, issue not resolved, can you guide for correct one ?

Comment: share the Entity mapping for other entities that you have used in Customer Entity

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/javaHelper/spring-data-jpa/tree/master/spring-boot-jpa-mysql-complex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding -

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while using yml/yaml format:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
```

The issue arises when using a different field/datatype in script table than the Entity/Model defined in code.
In my case,

- the flyway performed database creation/migration with .sql script which had BIGSERIAL datatype, ddl-auto: validate compares that with class annotated @Entity where same field was expecting an Integer. Since the match fails (fields or datatypes mismatch) it throws error in bean creation.

## Fix:

- Best fix will be making both databases 'perfectly' consistent.
- Possible workaround: try using ddl-auto: create (it will destroy bad schema and create the match) then update back to ddl-auto:validate and rerun application. (it will work, only downside is that you might have to do this every time when you change the schemas or entity)
- Setting ddl-auto:create-drop will work fine but it will destroy database when server terminate, so just use it for testing.
  I will try to find a better fix similar to Prateek but for yml, as soon as find I will update the post.
  I mentioned it for yaml format, but logic is same when using properties file.

## In case you want to dive deeper

- You can read more about ddl-auto property working and bit about best practices at: [How does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property exactly work in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)