# The delete method from JpaRepository deletes all rows from the DB table

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an `Admin` class that can delete `cooks` from the database by `id`. When I use the void `deleteByUserRoleAndId(String role, Long id)` method; it removes all columns from the database, but only one is needed, and also clears all cross-tables that are associated with this table! What could be my problem?

Cook:

```java
public class Cook {

    public Cook() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    // Поля

    // name, lastName, login, password берем от класса User через связи;

    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private CookType cookType;

    @Column(name = "rating")
    private float rating;

    @Column(name = "cook_status")
    private boolean cookStatus;

    @Column(name = "about_cook")
    private String aboutCook;


    //Relationships
    //
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // Join without Cook in User class
    private User user;

    // Лист отзывов
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cook", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Review> reviewList;

    // Лист поваров
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cook", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Order> orderList;

    // Лист блюд
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "cook_dish",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cook_id"))
    @JsonIgnore // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Dish> dish;
}
```

JpaRepo:

```java
public interface CookRepository extends JpaRepository<Cook, Long> { // Интерфейс для репозитория Cook


    // Удалить Повара Role + ID
    void deleteByUserRoleAndId(String role, Long id);
```

AdminService:

```java
@Transactional
    public void deleteCook(Long id) {

        cookRepository.deleteByUserRoleAndId("COOK", id);

    }
```

AdminController:

```java
@DeleteMapping("/delete/cook/{id}")
    void removeCook(@PathVariable Long id) {
        adminService.deleteCook(id);
    }
```

Data is added to all tables when I run the application using the script, and then when this method is executed, it is cleared!

[image]

[image]

I'm writing the `REST` of the app, using the download `Spring boot` + `Spring MVC` + `Spring Security` + `hibernate` + `Jpa` + `PostgreSQL`

Comment: it removes all columns from the database ?? you mean rows ?

Comment: all the data filled in, Yes

Comment: Can you enable show_sql and see what query hibernate is generating while deleting. Also one more thing is since ID is a primary key I thing deleteByID(Long  id) should be fine.

Comment: maybe this is working incorrectly because how am I doing something wrong with cascades?

Comment: Can you show the data in the db before it gets deleted?

Comment: @Transactional


    int headFoot = entityManager.createQuery("DELETE FROM HeaderFooterUpload HeadFoot").executeUpdate();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model class I remove `cascade = CascadeType.All` and add `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST`. And then in the class `Dish` I did the same.

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "cook_dish",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cook_id"))
    @JsonIgnore 
    private List<Dish> dish;
```

Comment: But then it doesnt remove anything. No record gets removed.. this doesnt fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a class and a database table called “Cook”, that has a unique Id.   You want to delete one particular cook that you identify by that Id - eg, you want to delete the cook with Id 123.

Nowhere in that is there a “UserRole”.  You don’t need the role - you already know you’re dealing with the Cook table.   In fact, the class “Cook” does not even have a “UserRole” property.

So spring tries to interpret `deleteByUserRoleAndId` as best it can.  In the absence of a “userRole” property, it probably tries to match the “User” from your function name against the “User” property that DOES exist (for comparison, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html says that `findByAddressZipCode(ZipCode zipCode);` will traverse across the `address` property).  What happens after that I can only guess.

Regardless, the solution is simple.   Since `Cook` does not have a `UserRole`, then do not have UserRole in the method name.

So the method signatory is simply :

```
void deleteById(Long id);
```

And the service is :

```
@Transactional
public void deleteCook(Long id) {

    cookRepository.deleteById(id);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. My mistake was in application.properties file.

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =** **create-drop**

I should have used update or validate instead of create-drop

Please refer to [How does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property exactly work in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)