# Prevent @Entity from re creating a database table - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-jpa

I'm kinda new to spring boot data jpa, as far as I know @Entity is used to represent a database table in the application, for this project im using `spring-boot 2.2.5.RELEASE` and `H2` as in memory database.

So far I've got this.

inside of resources/data.sql

```
CREATE TABLE CURRENCY (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  code VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EXCHANGE_CURRENCY (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  IdFx1 INT NOT NULL,
  IdFx2 INT NOT NULL,
  equivalent DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (IdFx1) REFERENCES CURRENCY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (IdFx2) REFERENCES CURRENCY(id)
);
```

My entity class

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CURRENCY")
public class Currency {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
}
```

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CurrencyRepository extends CrudRepository<Currency, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM CURRENCY WHERE c.code LIKE %:code%")
    List<Currency> findCurrencyByCode(@Param("code") String code);

}
```

And service

```
import com.currency.canonical.models.Currency;
import com.currency.canonical.request.ExchangeValueRequest;
import com.currency.canonical.response.ExchangeValueResponse;
import com.currency.dao.CurrencyService;
import com.currency.dao.repository.CurrencyRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class CurrencyConversionServiceImpl implements CurrencyConversionService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrencyConversionServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

    @Override
    public ExchangeValueResponse performCurrencyConversion(ExchangeValueRequest request) {
        final long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ExchangeValueResponse objExchangeValueResponse = new ExchangeValueResponse();

        try {
            List<Currency> currencyList = currencyRepository.findCurrencyByCode(request.getMonedaOrigen());
            currencyList.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return objExchangeValueResponse;
    }
}
```

When executing the app I got this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/IdeaProjects/currency-converter/currency-converter-resource/target/classes/data.sql]: CREATE TABLE CURRENCY ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, code VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabla "CURRENCY" ya existe
Table "CURRENCY" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE CURRENCY ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, code VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ) [42101-200]
```

Why is the @Entity trying to re create a table that is supposed to only represent, and is there a way to disable this?

Comment: You are using H2 an in-memory database. For this Spring Boot automatically creates the tables based on the entities, you can disable this by specifying `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` (or `validate` to have some sense of validity) in your `application.properties`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is the name of the file **data.sql**, as suggested by spring there are two important files that will help you control the database creation, these are namely

- `schema.sql` - This file as the name suggest hold are the DDL statements required of creating schema of the database.
- `data.sql` - This file will hold all the DML statements required to populate the initial database correctly.

Issue with your application is that the DDL is specified in the `data.sql` file, this confuses spring and it tries to execute DDL as considering it's DML.

The solution to you issue is simply rename `data.sql` to `schema.sql` and spring will handle the rest.

Also I found one more issue with the repository, since you are using a custom Query `@Query("SELECT code FROM CURRENCY WHERE code LIKE %:code%")` would likely cause and error when the repository is initiated because java entity names are case-sensitive. You can solve this issue in following ways -

A. Since its a like query spring repository already supports its and you can rewrite method like -

```
List<Currency> findByCodeLike(@Param("code") String code);
```

B. Use JPQL queries, same as you did in the code except changing the table name since JPA entity names are case-sensitive

```
@Query("SELECT code FROM Currency WHERE code LIKE %:code%")
List<Currency> findCurrencyByCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

C. If you still wanna keep the current query with table name as in db schema "CURRENCY", then you can use `nativeQuery` flag in `@Query` to let spring know that you are using native queries and not JPQL -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT code FROM CURRENCY WHERE code LIKE %:code%", nativeQuery = true)
List<Currency> findCurrencyByCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this answer explains better the reason and should be the correct answer. The problem is that data.sql is for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE and runs after the entities are created. It should be `schema.sql`

Comment: As the documentation says: in a JPA-based app, you can choose to let Hibernate create the schema or use schema.sql, but you cannot do both. is also necessary to add this property on the application.properties file

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Answer (score 3):

JPA has features for DDL generation, and these can be set up to run on startup against the database. This is controlled through two external properties:

1. `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` (boolean) switches the feature on and off
   and is vendor independent.
2. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` (enum) is a Hibernate feature that
   controls the behavior in a more fine-grained way.

Reference [spring boot JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

How does the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property work? you can refer below config's based on environment.

- Development - create-drop, update
- production - none

  [How does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property exactly work in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)

Answer (score 1):

An error occurs because when you run your application it tries to recreate the table, as a workaround for the same is as follow:

1. Add a `drop table if exists [tablename]` in your data.sql before you create the table.
2. Change the statement from `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: This actually doesn't explain why is happening and it is a workaround instead, shouldn't be the correct answer.