# Spring JPA + Oracle 12 C Schema Validation Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, oracle12c

Facing schema validation issue in "Spring Boot + JPA + Oracle 12C". This work as expected with Postgres database.

After debugging further I found that the below code snippet from class `InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl` returns an empty table list due to which hibernate tries to **create** tables instead of **update** existing tables.

```
ResultSet resultSet = 
     extractionContext.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData()
                      .getTables(catalogFilter,
                                 schemaFilter,
                                 "%",
                                 tableTypes);
```

**Datasource/TransactionManager etc. Configuration**

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "first-db")
public DataSource firstDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource hikariDS = new HikariDataSource();
    hikariDS.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.jdbc-url"));
    hikariDS.setUsername(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.username"));
    hikariDS.setPassword(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.password"));
    hikariDS.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.driver-class-name"));      
    
    hikariDS.setConnectionTimeout(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout", Integer.class));
    hikariDS.setIdleTimeout(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout", Integer.class));
    hikariDS.setMaxLifetime(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime", Integer.class));
    hikariDS.setMinimumIdle(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle", Integer.class));      
    hikariDS.setMaximumPoolSize(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size", Integer.class));     
    hikariDS.setPoolName(env.getProperty("primary.datasource.hikari.pool-name", String.class));
    
    return hikariDS;
}


@Primary
@Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
@Qualifier("primary")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean firstEntityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =  new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(firstDataSource());

    // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
            env.getProperty("first.entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.getBoolean(env.getProperty("first.hibernate.show_sql")));
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("first.hibernate.dialect"));
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE); //Database.POSTGRESQL

    // Hibernate properties
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("first.hibernate.dialect"));
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("first.hibernate.show_sql"));
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("first.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaProperties.setProperty("database-platform", env.getProperty("first.hibernate.dialect"));
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");

    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
    jpaProperties.setProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
    jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");

    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("EWS-Primary-DB");

    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Primary
@Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager() {       
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(firstEntityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return tm;
}
```

**Framework Code (GroupSchemaMigratorImpl.java)**

```
final NameSpaceTablesInformation tables = existingDatabase.getTablesInformation( namespace );
for ( Table table : namespace.getTables() ) {
    if ( schemaFilter.includeTable( table ) && table.isPhysicalTable() ) {
        checkExportIdentifier( table, exportIdentifiers );
        final TableInformation tableInformation = tables.getTableInformation( table );
        if ( tableInformation == null ) {
            createTable( table, dialect, metadata, formatter, options, targets );
        }
        else if ( tableInformation != null && tableInformation.isPhysicalTable() ) {
            tablesInformation.addTableInformation( tableInformation );
            migrateTable( table, tableInformation, dialect, metadata, formatter, options, targets );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the way how you configure data source XML or pure bean configuration?

Answer (score 0):

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created with:

`update` : update the schema and create a new one if not exists

`create` : creates the schema, destroying previous data

`create-drop` : drops the schema when the application is stopped or SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

`validate`: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database, and this is the recommended one for a production environment.

I didn't notice the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` since `first.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is not defined in your question, anyway in your case you have to change it to `validate` or `update`.

just change the value of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `validate`

Comment: I am unable to add content application properties.. All these properties are defines there.

Comment: @VishalPatil make sure the table exists and change `first.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `validate` since the `update` will create the table if it's not exists

Comment: Table already exist in database. When I set the proper first.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate, the I get bellow error

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [`external_rating_error_stg`]

Comment: @VishalPatil its another thread, have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479406/schema-validation-missing-table-game

Comment: Thanks for info, Have tried few options from the link provided. Did not work though.

Comment: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getTables is returning empty resultset this is the reason hibernate validate/update schema operation is failing. Looks like some issue drive version. Have tried all available drive version but same result

Comment: My problem is similar to this I am using java 1.8 still get this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056965/spring-boot-with-hibernate-and-oracle-cant-find-existing-table

Comment: The property "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" was set to false, this was causing entire problem. Issue has been resolved with below change
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=true

Answer (score 0):

The property "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" was set to false in my code, this was causing entire problem. Issue has been resolved with below change hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=true