# What is the difference between ddl-auto and hbm2ddl.auto?

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

Every time I try to start "Spring Boot Dashboard" from VSCode I get an error while using the following command.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update        (Doesn't Work)
```

However, I managed to find this line here on stack overflow that made it work. The problem is I don't know the difference and how will it impact my production.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update    (Works)
```

Any sort of help would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto)

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` This is actually a shortcut for the `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` property.

Defaults to `"create-drop"` when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. Otherwise, defaults to `"none"`.

From this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring/42147995#42147995)

In production, it's often highly recommended you use `none` or simply don't specify this property. That is because it's common practice for DBAs to review migration scripts for database changes, particularly if your database is shared across multiple services and applications.