# I get empty list from findAll Spring data and h2 data base while the database is not empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I have a spring boot API project with h2 database.
I added some data in the data.sql but the data wasn't inserted into the database however tables are created successfully when I call the findAll API I get an empty list due to the database tables are empty.

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

server.port=8888
```

data.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS device;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gateway;

CREATE TABLE gateway (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    serial_number VARCHAR(250) UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR(250),
    address VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE device (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    UID INT UNIQUE,
    vendor VARCHAR(250),
    created DATE,
    status BOOLEAN,
    gateway_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (gateway_id) REFERENCES gateway(id)
);


INSERT INTO gateway (id, serial_number, name, address) VALUES (1,'GTW-1','Gateway 1','123.187.65.1');
INSERT INTO gateway (id, serial_number, name, address) VALUES (2,'GTW-2','Gateway 2','123.187.65.2');
INSERT INTO gateway (id, serial_number, name, address) VALUES (3,'GTW-3','Gateway 3','123.187.65.3');
INSERT INTO gateway (id, serial_number, name, address) VALUES (4,'GTW-4','Gateway 4','123.187.65.4');


INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (1,001,'huawei', parsedatetime('17-09-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), true, 1);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (2,002,'intel', parsedatetime('11-07-2013', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), false, 1);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (3,003,'sony', parsedatetime('01-01-2015', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 1);

INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (4,004,'sony', parsedatetime('17-09-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 2);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (5,005,'huawei', parsedatetime('11-10-2013', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 2);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (6,006,'dell', parsedatetime('04-05-2010', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 2);


INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (7,007,'sony', parsedatetime('13-09-2020', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),false, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (8,008,'dell', parsedatetime('05-09-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),false, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (9,009,'intel', parsedatetime('12-12-2013', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (10,010,'dell', parsedatetime('17-07-2009', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),false, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (11,011,'sony', parsedatetime('15-05-2015', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (12,012,'toshiba', parsedatetime('09-09-2017', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (13,013,'intel', parsedatetime('10-10-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (14,014,'dell', parsedatetime('11-11-2011', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (15,015,'sony', parsedatetime('01-06-2021', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),false, 3);
INSERT INTO device (id, UID, vendor, created, status, gateway_id) VALUES (16,016,'sony', parsedatetime('17-06-2012', 'dd-MM-yyyy'),true, 3);
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateways</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gateways</name>
    <description>gateways</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Gateway.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gateway")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Gateway {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="serial_number", unique = true)
    private String serialNumber;
    
    @Column(name="name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gateway")
    private List<Device> devices;
    
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface GatewayRepository extends JpaRepository<Gateway, Long>{

}
```

Controller

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gateway")
public class GatewayController {

    @Autowired
    GatewayRepository gatewayRepository;
    
    @GetMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<List<Gateway>> getAllGateways() {
        try {
            List<Gateway> gateways = gatewayRepository.findAll();
            if (gateways.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(gateways, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

project structure

[image]

Comment: Please check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp, your insert sql should specify the columns.

Comment: You are using the an all and no argument constructor, but you don't have getter/setter, this might cause Hibernate to not be able to set the values properly. Try adding a Getter/Setter annotation on class level.

Comment: @Data means generation of getters and setters however I tried to add them , but didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property exactly work in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your application properties to stop JPA auto generating your `gateway` table over the top of your `data.sql`.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

By the way, this is the only thing you need in your `application.properties`, as all the rest is default.