# How to use an existing table in MySQL in a new Spring Boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, api, rest

i have an existing database and existing table my MySQL database that holds data. I want to perform a get to display all data the from the existing table to the user. however, every tutorial i find involves creating a new database and a new table of example data, but i want to import an already existing database and table into a new Spring Boot application to perform endpoint functions on it. how do i go about this? thanks.
(assume it's production data in the database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the following steps, using JPA

1. add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa depdency
2. configure database-connection in your application.properties

   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

   spring.datasource.url=...

   spring.datasource.username=...

   spring.datasource.password=...

   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=...
3. Write Entities to represent your existing tables
4. Create JPA-Repositories for the entities
5. Create service(s) to access your database
6. Create a controller and inject the service(s)

The spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property is important to ensure that you do not delete or modify existing entries on startup/cleanup. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring).