# Trouble creating table spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I have created the following entity using Kotlin + Spring but it seems that the table is not being generated in my postgreSQL database. The other entities from the project were generated just fine. Where do you think I should start my investigation from?

Here is the code for the above mentioned entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne
import jakarta.persistence.Table
import java.util.*
@Table(name ="appointments")
@Entity
class Appointments : ParentModelObject() {
    var date: Date? = null

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "professional")
    var professional: Professionals? = null

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    var user: AccountDetails? = null

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service")
    var service: Services? = null

}
```

I tried deleting the entire database and creating it again from scratch but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Database creation shouldn't be handled by Hibernate, especially in production code. That being said it is also disabled by default for non in-memory databases and you need to enable it explicitly (exactly for the reason given at first).

Comment: This SO answer gives details about how to invoke the automatic database creation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147995/1847378

Comment: try not using `user` keyword